# How do I normalize the signal generated from wfbm in matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, simulation, physics, wavelet

I am using matlab's [wavelet fractional Brownian motion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wfbm.html) function in order to generate 1D point-like data of a diffusive particle in the physical regimes: sub-diffusion, super-diffusion and normal diffusion.

The  problem I encounter with is that the time normalization/variance is weird.

For example for Hurst parameter equals `0.5` (regular Brownian motion) I get standard deviation which isn't unity (`1`):

```
>> std(diff(wfbm(0.5,1e6)))

ans =

    0.3955
```

Due to the above, I am not sure how to re-normalize all the 3 trajectories I create for the 3 diffusion cases (sub, super, normal).

---

I generated trajectories for `N` pointlike particles of length `M`:

```
M=500;
N=200;
nd  = zeros(M,N);
sub = zeros(M,N);
sup = zeros(M,N);
Hsub = 0.25;
Hsup = 0.75;

for j=1:N
    nd(:,j)  = wfbm(0.5, M, 15, 'db10');
    sub(:,j) = wfbm(Hsub,M, 10, 'db10');
    sup(:,j) = wfbm(Hsup,M, 10, 'db10');
end
```

---

Here is how function is implemented in matlab and generates the signal, however I am not sure how to modify it to have a proper brownian motion:

```
tmp = conv(randn(1,len+nbmax),ckbeta);
tmp = cumsum(tmp);
CA  = wkeep(tmp,len,'c');
for j=0:nblev-1
    CD  = 2^(j/2)*4^(-s)*2^(-j*s)*randn(1,len);
    len = 2*len-nbmax;
    CA  = idwt(CA,CD,fs1,gs1,len);
end
fBm  = wkeep(CA,L,'c');
fBm  = fBm-fBm(1);
```

I was trying to understand it from the [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063520396900305) which says it's possible to control the variance of fBm:

[image]

[This](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/119751/) is citation 7 from the snapshot above.